# FileSystemWatcher locks folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` listening on a folder. When I try renaming  this folder (in Windows Explorer) I get a

> The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is
>   open in another program

error.

Commenting out the `FileSystemWatcher` calls fixes this.

I've tried reproducing the error with a simple program, but haven't been successful so I'm not sure what's going on here. Has anyone encountered  anything like this with a `FileSystemWatcher`? If so  - what might be causing it?

**More information:**

The following seems to be enough to cause the error:

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Deleted);
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

I *can* rename files in that folder. And sibling files. I even tried putting a `return;` as the first line in `fsw_Deleted`. Still didn't work. As didn't closing Visual Studio, and deleting obj and bin, and running again. And I even tried running the exe file not within VS. Still - no lock if it's not running, Locked if it is.

Comment: No, FileSystemWatcher doesn't lock (case in point: [C# FileSystemWatcher lock folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973477/c-sharp-filesystemwatcher-lock-folder)). There probably was something in your `fsw_Deleted` that locks the directory or a file in it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I even tried putting a `return;` as the first line in `fsw_Deleted`. Still didn't work. As didn't closing Visual Studio, and deleting `obj` and `bin`. I don't know what more can I try. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry. No. I meant doing that, _and_ running again. And I even tried running the `exe` file not within VS. Still - no lock if it's not running, Locked if it is.

Comment: But we can't know what other code is running, as you didn't show it. And as you have noticed, the code you do show doesn't cause the issue you describe. I'm afraid there's simply not enough information in your question to analyze this problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster No other running program doing it, since when I close this program - I can rename it. As for your last comment - Yes, I definitely understand this is little to go by. That's why my question was phrased as it was - I'm looking for someone who had a similar experience and would say - Yes, it's XYZ. Thanks, though. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've found the answer - see my answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've discovered what caused this. There was a second `FileSystemWatcher` - on a sub directory of the first - which didn't allow renaming the first.

<sub>(I'm still surprised, though. A `FileSystemWatcher` *should* be "invisible".)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Its going to do that, since your process is looking for files in that folder.  What you may want to do is add a handler for fsw.Rename.  Then inside that process you should do a RemoveHandler on looking for new files, and then add it back in with the new name of the folder.