# FileSystemWatcher locks parent folder, is there a fix or an alternative?

Tags: c#, .net

Whether in .NET Core or .NET Framework, the use of a FileSystemWatcher on a folder makes it impossible to delete any parent folder with File Explorer.
File Explorer will ask you for admin rights. Launching File Explorer as admin doesn't fix the issue.

The only way that I can make it work is to set the FileSystemWatcher to the root drive, and include subdirectories, which could lead to big performance issues, and a buffer overflow on the FSW.

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\One\Two\Three");
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

You will not be able to delete folders 'One' or 'Two'.
The problem starts as soon as set 'EnableRaisingEvents' to true, but if you don't, you will not get any notification.

Is there a way to overcome this problem, or an alternative to FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: It shouldn't, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224595/filesystemwatcher-locks-folder. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: But Eric it is not specified for which kind of file changes you are adding filewatcher.
You should use 'NotifyFilter'. There are too many kind file attributes, which one you are planning target?

Comment: @CodeCaster I read your link before, and it's not the same problem. On your link, it was caused by a second FileSystemWatcher. Mine is about the parents of the folder being watched. The two lines of code I wrote are enough to reproduce the problem, it is an actual minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ANaik of course in my code I fully configure it with NotifyFilters, events, etc...I kept it short to highlight the problem

Comment: @EricP. It's the same issue, the second watcher was looking at a subfolder and the OP was trying to rename the parent folder.  The issue in that question is not caused by having multiple watchers; it's caused by having *a* watcher watching a subfolder of a folder the user is trying to alter.  The accepted answer to that question isn't a good answer, though.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` will get a lock on the parent folder structure, preventing deletions or renaming (which alters the tree structure) of any folder in the tree from root to the watched folder.  The only workaround is to not use a `FileSystemWatcher`: use a thread to check the folder for changes periodically.

Comment: @Amy Right, but there is no solution on the post mentionned. The OP Marked his discovery related to the second FSW as solution, but it is of no help for me. The reason of my post is to know if there is a workaround or an alternative to this limitation.

Comment: @EricP. I agree it isn't helpful; it is, however, the same issue.

Comment: What made me think there would be a solution is that FSW has an 'Error' event, which should be triggered if the FSW is not able to monitor the folder anymore. To me that would happen if the parent'd get deleted.
Maybe someone knows a way to use the WINAPI to have the benefits of FSW without the drawbacks?

Comment: @EricP. Internally, `FSW` has a private method `StartRaisingEvents` that has this line:  `directoryHandle = Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods.CreateFile(directory, 1, 7, null, 3, 1107296256, new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, ownsHandle: false));`  In Windows, file handles acquire a lock on the parent structure so the handle remains valid for the lifetime of the handle.  The issue isn't caused by `FSW` itself; it's caused by how the WINAPI works.

Comment: @EricP. See https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs#L979

Comment: @Amy Thank you very much.

Comment: You're watching `@"C:\One\Two\Three"`. Set the watcher to the upper-level directory, i.e., change it to `@"C:\One"`. You won't lock its sub-directories (nor `@"C:\One"`). Set `.IncludeSubdirectories = true` to receive notification on all the brach, or `.IncludeSubdirectories = false` to only be notified about `Two`. Include a *manual* filter if required.

Comment: I can't see your code, but - if you haven't - call `fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` after you have set everything else (including the handlers, of course), possibly in a `BeginInit()/EndInit()` block.

Answer (score 0):

@EricP gave the root cause: The FSW internally makes a call to CreateFileW to open a handle to the monitored directory Three, which tells Windows to prevent deleting the parent folders One and Two.

But the CreateFileW call is made with read+write+delete sharing mode, meaning Windows should allow any other processes to delete the monitored folder Three.

So there's no direct fix for your problem, but there is a workaround:

Delete Three first, which should release the handle, then delete Two and/or One, which should be allowed.

Here's a code sample reproing this without any FileSystemWatcher code, just direct Windows P/Invokes:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Desktop\parent\child";

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new Exception("Make sure to create the directories before testing.");
            }

            // This will lock the directory
            SafeFileHandle _directoryHandle = CreateFile(
                lpFileName: path,
                dwDesiredAccess: 0x0001, //FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
                dwShareMode: FileShare.Read | FileShare.Delete | FileShare.Write,
                dwCreationDisposition: FileMode.Open,
                dwFlagsAndAttributes:
                    0x02000000 /*FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS*/ |
                    0x40000000 /*FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED*/
                );

            Console.WriteLine("Try to manually delete the 'parent' directory using File Explorer. It should fail.");
            Console.WriteLine("Now try to manually delete the 'child' directory, then the 'parent' directory, using File Explorer. It should succeed.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            _directoryHandle.Dispose();
        }

        internal enum BOOL : int
        {
            FALSE = 0,
            TRUE = 1,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            internal uint nLength;
            internal IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            internal BOOL bInheritHandle;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern unsafe SafeFileHandle CreateFilePrivate(
            string lpFileName,
            int dwDesiredAccess,
            FileShare dwShareMode,
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* lpSecurityAttributes,
            FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
            int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        internal static unsafe SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
            string lpFileName,
            int dwDesiredAccess,
            FileShare dwShareMode,
            FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
            int dwFlagsAndAttributes)
        {
            return CreateFilePrivate(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, null, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```